# How to configuration forgot password mailtrap to gmail laravel 8

Tags: laravel, authentication, gmail, forgot-password, mailtrap

I have a problem with the forgotten password process in laravel 8, initially I used mailtrap for the forgotten password process, but now I want to use gmail for the forgotten password process, does anyone understand how to configure mailtrap to gmail ?, what should i do for the first step

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the mail setting in the .env:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=YOUR_GMAIL@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=PASSWORD
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```